# Put tick mark in word document

Tags: ms-word

How can I put a tick mark in word document?  I want to put a tick mark in a box, say male/female.

I am using MS Word 2013.

Comment: The link here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-add-checkbox-controls-to-a-word-document/ probably would help you out.

Comment: Do you mean a checkbox control that can be toggled by the user, or a symbol (character) that is just part of the content, such as “☑” (U+2611 BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the Developer tab, then insert a checkbox from the Controls section.